# How to calculate days of readmission

Tags: r, date, datetime

From the following data frame, I would like to make a new column of numbers of days between discharge_date to the next admission_date from each id.
I know how to get the number of days by subtracting dates between rows or between columns, but in this case, I need to subtract dates between columns and between rows (diagonally)

```
df <- data.table(id = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C"), 
           admission_date = as.Date(c("2017-01-01", "2017-02-01", "2017-05-01", "2017-01-01", "2017-05-01", "2017-10-01", "2017-01-01", "2017-02-01")), 
           discharge_date = as.Date(c("2017-01-04", "2017-02-05", "2017-05-06", "2017-01-03", "2017-05-09", "2017-10-04", "2017-01-06", "2017-02-01")))
```

I expect results like this:

```
df <- data.table(id = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C"), 
                 admission_date = as.Date(c("2017-01-01", "2017-02-01", "2017-05-01", "2017-01-01", "2017-05-01", "2017-10-01", "2017-01-01", "2017-02-01")), 
                 discharge_date = as.Date(c("2017-01-04", "2017-02-05", "2017-05-06", "2017-01-03", "2017-05-09", "2017-10-04", "2017-01-06", "2017-02-01")))
                 DayReadmission <- c("NA", "28", "85", "NA", "118", "145", "NA", "26")
```

I have just started using R, and have tried various suggestions. However, none of them fit my needs.

Comment: You're looking for `lag`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `shift` to get value from previous row.

```
library(data.table)
df[, DayReadmission := as.numeric(admission_date - shift(discharge_date)), id]

df
#   id admission_date discharge_date DayReadmission
#1:  A     2017-01-01     2017-01-04             NA
#2:  A     2017-02-01     2017-02-05             28
#3:  A     2017-05-01     2017-05-06             85
#4:  B     2017-01-01     2017-01-03             NA
#5:  B     2017-05-01     2017-05-09            118
#6:  B     2017-10-01     2017-10-04            145
#7:  C     2017-01-01     2017-01-06             NA
#8:  C     2017-02-01     2017-02-01             26
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(DayReadmission = admission_date - lag(discharge_date))
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this, and successfully solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Since you're new to R, this is the "old school" approach.

```
df$DayReadmission <- unlist(lapply(split(df, df$id), 
       FUN=function(x) x$admission_date - lag(x$discharge_date)))

#  id admission_date discharge_date DayReadmission
#1  A     2017-01-01     2017-01-04             NA
#2  A     2017-02-01     2017-02-05             28
#3  A     2017-05-01     2017-05-06             85
#4  B     2017-01-01     2017-01-03             NA
#5  B     2017-05-01     2017-05-09            118
#6  B     2017-10-01     2017-10-04            145
#7  C     2017-01-01     2017-01-06             NA
#8  C     2017-02-01     2017-02-01             26
```